# What to do after gettting .po files and .mo files while translating documentation using Sphinx Internationalization?

Tags: python-3.x, internationalization, python-sphinx

I am using Sphinx Internationalization to translate documents. I am following the steps as told in their documentation - https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx-intl.

I have generated the .mo files, but when I run the command -

```
make -e SPHINXOPTS="-D language='es'" html
```

I am not getting the HTML files. I have also tried

```
make -e SPHINXOPTS="-D language=es" html
```

And this is not working as well. What should I do to get the translated HTML files?

I am working on Windows 10.

Comment: Did you `make clean`? By default Sphinx does not overwrite its output files unless you change the source reST file. You can also delete your build directory, which is the same as `make clean`. Also do you get any error messages?

Comment: @StevePiercy what do you mean by make clean? I am following the steps as mentioned in the official documentation. I am not getting any error messages. Also, do we have to manually change something in the .po files? I have generated both the .po and .mo files.

Comment: I mean exactly what I said: "You can also delete your build directory, which is the same as `make clean`."

Comment: @StevePiercy I got the issue. Thanks for the concern and help.